# What determines how much structural damage a stack does?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

In order to quickly break down the defenses of an enemy town or fort, your creature stacks have the option to attack the door and the walls.  Sometimes my creatures do 1 structural point of damage, while at other times they do 2.  What determines how much structural damage a creature stack does?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The damage is determined by the physical size of the unit.

A unit that needs one tile does 1 point of damage. A 2x2 unit does 2 points damage.